# The requested url was not found in this server using yii2 + xampp in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, yii2

Yesterday my app was running smoothly. Now, I can't run the app, this error shows when I try to access any url:

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

Error logs:

```
[Sat May 28 11:27:23.026525 2016] [:error] [pid 3313] [client 127.0.0.1:39322] script '/opt/lampp/htdocs/project-final/backend/web/index.php' not found or unable to stat

and the access log:

127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2016:11:28:11 +0200] "GET /project-final/backend/web/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 1031
127.0.0.1 - - [28/May/2016:11:28:28 +0200] "GET /project-final/backend/web/index.php?r=gii HTTP/1.1" 404 1031
```

First thing I've tried is comming back to older versions of my projects, nothing happened. After that, I tried using custom url rules or adding the recommended yii2 .htaccess file, same happens. I didn't change or added anything to xampp configuration, I just went to sleep and when I woke up server wasn't working.

I've also tried running 127.0.0.1 instead localhost. I've created a custom host:

```
127.0.0.1   yii.local
```

I can access the project file tree using http://yii.local but urls are not working again.

My config/main.php:

```
        <?php
    $params = array_merge(
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
        require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
    );

    return [
        'id' => 'app-backend',
        'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
        'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers',
        'bootstrap' => ['log'],
        'modules' => [],
        'components' => [
            'user' => [
                'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
                'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            ],
            'log' => [
                'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
                'targets' => [
                    [


             'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: plase show your related code  ..

Comment: What do you want to see?

Comment: The link you are using  and the eventually the code where link/url is used ..

Comment: For example, I always used this url to access gii generator: http://localhost/gestiontaller-final/backend/web/index.php?r=car now it's nt working anymore.

Comment: have you change urlManager config?

Comment: I didn't, what should I check?

Comment: config/main.php ..   component urlManager ..

Comment: added to my original post if you can check it. I don't have any urlManager component.

Comment: Have you change htaccess . of some other config for you Web Server manager ?

Comment: I'm not running .htaccess , I've just tried using it for testing. And no, same for web server manager/config. It just stopped working after rebooting.

Comment: I have posted a brief suggestion but could be during you .htacces test you have setted somethins ...

Comment: Tried creating a new project, issue persists so I think it's server-related.

Comment: Yes ... could be some residual .htaccess somewhere ..

Comment: Not an option since I checkout older commits where I don't have any .htaccess files. I will uninstall lampp and try.